# How to find impulse response $h(t)$, given an output of LTI system?

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

> A LTI system takes $x(t)$ as input and $y(t)$ as output. Given $$y(t)=\int_{t-5}^{t-1}2x(\tau)d\tau$$, how to find $h(t)$, the impulse response?

Convolution $x(t)*h(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau$, so by comparing this to the given output, $h(t)$ is $2\delta(t)$, is this correct?

Comment: No it's not. If it were the delta the output would have been $2x(t)$, not that integral.

Comment: What if you let the input to the system, x(t), be an impulse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use $\delta(t)$ as the input. By definition you get $h(t)$ as the output:
$$y(t)=\int_{t-5}^{t-1}2x(\tau)d\tau$$
$$h(t)
=\int_{t-5}^{t-1}2\delta(\tau)d\tau
=2\int_{t-5}^{t-1}\delta(\tau)d\tau
=\left\{
\begin{array}{r,l}
2,& t-5<0<t-1\\
0,& otherwise
\end{array}\right.
=\left\{
\begin{array}{r,l}
2,& 1<t<5\\
0,& otherwise
\end{array}\right.$$
It is a square pulse. You can also write it as a combination of step functions:
$$h(t)=2\left[u(t-1)-u(t-5)\right].$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Convolution is commutative, so use the variable substitution $\tau = t-\tau'$. Don't forget to change the bounds, too. Can you see what function is integrated against $x$ now?